# Unable to reduce an array of objects based on string value

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

So I have this array of objects which I need to reduce based on each object's prop value as well as count the total.

What I mean to say is, suppose I have this array of objects:

```
[
     { dateTime: '2021-07-30', count: 4 },
     { dateTime: '2021-07-31', count: 1 },
     { dateTime: '2021-08-01', count: 2 },
     { dateTime: '2021-08-02', count: 1 },
     { dateTime: '2021-08-03', count: 2 },
     { dateTime: '2021-08-04', count: 3 }
]
```

I want to reduce it to something like this:

```
[
     { month: '2021-07', count: 5 },
     { month: '2021-08', count: 8 }
]
```

Here's the snippet:

```js
const data = [{
    dateTime: '2021-07-30',
    count: 4
  },
  {
    dateTime: '2021-07-31',
    count: 1
  },
  {
    dateTime: '2021-08-01',
    count: 2
  },
  {
    dateTime: '2021-08-02',
    count: 1
  },
  {
    dateTime: '2021-08-03',
    count: 2
  },
  {
    dateTime: '2021-08-04',
    count: 3
  }
];

const stackedMonths = data.reduce((acc, curr) => {

  return [{
    month: curr.dateTime.slice(0, 7),
    count: acc + curr.count
  }];

}, []);

console.log(stackedMonths);
```

After trying the code, I'm getting this which doesn't make any sense:

```
[ { month: '2021-08', count: '[object Object]2' } ]
```

What am I doing wrong here? Please note that I'm new to reduce and I'm still learning it.

Comment: On this line, `count: acc + curr.count`, `acc` is an object. When you concatenate an object with a number, you get a string (unless you have a toValue method on the object that returns a number.) Surely you didn't intend to concatenate an object with a number?

Comment: No I did not. I was trying it out myself from various answers here in SO. But isn't acc an array?

Comment: An Array is an Object. You can't add numbers to an Object itself, as an Object isn't a Number (or any form of a Number).

Comment: @esqew Understood. Thanks

Comment: It should be an array, but if it was, you wouldn't get `[object Object]2`. Yes, arrays are objects, but arrays have a different outcome when concatenating in this way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Array#reduce` with an object to store the sum for each month.

```js
const arr = [
     { dateTime: '2021-07-30', count: 4 },
     { dateTime: '2021-07-31', count: 1 },
     { dateTime: '2021-08-01', count: 2 },
     { dateTime: '2021-08-02', count: 1 },
     { dateTime: '2021-08-03', count: 2 },
     { dateTime: '2021-08-04', count: 3 }
];
const res = Object.values(arr.reduce((acc, curr)=>{
  const month = curr.dateTime.slice(0, -3);
  (acc[month] ??= {month, count: 0}).count += curr.count;
  return acc;
}, {}));
console.log(res);
```

If the value of `month` does not yet exist as a key on the accumulator, it is set to `{month: month, count: 0}`. Then, the `count` is incremented by the current object's count.

Comment: Hi. Can you please explain this part ```(acc[month] ??= {month, count: 0}).count += curr.count;```?

Comment: @s.khan If the value of `month` does not yet exist as a key on the accumulator, it is set to `{month: month, count: 0}`. Then, the count is incremented by the current object's count.

Comment: Very clever use of `Object.values` and `??=`, love the succinctness.

Comment: @Unmitigated hey man, I'm getting an error in NodeJS because of ```??=```  operator.

Comment: @s.khan You can replace that with `acc[month] =  acc[month] || {month, count: 0}`.

Comment: @Unmitigated oh you're a genius. Thanks